# Trying to add devise_invitable gem. :invitable in my devise model (User) is causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-invitable

I am trying to install scambra/devise_invitable gem. Both manual and automatic ways of installing it do not work.
I am adding the gem to the Gemfile, running bundle install, after which attempt to either run `rails generate devise_invitable:install` or `rails g migration CreateDeviseInvitable` with its corresponding code, and in both cases I am getting the stack trace placed in the gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0b40c1970dd586ed8c8. If I keep the module in my Gemfile, I am unable to generate to continue the steps decribed in https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable. I also cannot start the server anymore, unless I remove the gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [a fix for this was merged into devise_invitable on December 31, 2015](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/616). Your version of devise_invitable (1.5.5) was released on December 17, 2015. If you're committed to your current versions of Devise and Rails, you might try pulling the gem from [GitHub](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) instead of RubyGems.

Comment: Thanks @Wil for your response, I saw that fix, but didn't thought of trying to pull the gem from github. Will edit this comment and tell how whether or not that fixes it.